# Why does html { font-size: 1rem; } create 1px right border?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4. I have a navbar etc etc.

In learning about media queries, I discovered a CSS rule, which I am finding useful to drop my overall font size slightly...

```
html {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

The trouble is, when I do this, it seems to introduce a 1px right-hand border/gap to the entire page.

In [this animated .gif](http://g.recordit.co/qxCddtmVks.gif), you should see the difference between the normal size at `font-size: 1rem;`(no border) and, on reload, the border appearing when at `font-size: 0.9rem;`.

[image]

To be clear - the border does not appear immediately on load; I need to peek over to the right to reveal it. And, when I do, it stays visible.

Is this normal behaviour?
Are there any workarounds?

**Update:**

I should have posted some code - https://jsfiddle.net/iamrobertandrews/aq9Laaew/266266/

Comment: *I have a navbar etc etc.* --> all the *etc* are useful to us

Comment: Does it only appear when using `font-size`?

Comment: @Variable Yes - if I remove the rule entirely or change the font-size to 1, thereby normalising the font size, the right border doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Please post a fiddle with enough HTML/CSS that we can recreate the issue and poke around at what's happening... it's probably because something else in the page is sized in `rem` or `em`, but it's not possible to helpfully guess at the cause without inspecting it in action.

Comment: I should definitely have added some code - https://jsfiddle.net/iamrobertandrews/aq9Laaew/266266/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class in footer element p-4 instead of p-3, see below code-

```html
<footer class="container-fluid bg-dark text-white p-4">

</footer>
```

Comment: That does work, but please can you add some explanation? I'm curious why adding padding to the footer should cause any kind of right-hand expansion. If I use p-0, I get a big fat right-hand border. Padding is for *interior* padding, isn't it?

Comment: @Robert, 'container-fluid' have some padding and you change the padding at same class. If you add padding after div having 'container-fluid' class that type issue never comes.

Comment: I thought it was totally valid to add padding to .container-fluid?  Maybe I should abandon any p-* for .container-fluid, and instead apply my padding to the .row that's *inside* it.

Comment: Container-fluid already have padding 15px all sides if you reduce padding so it is give right side sapce because of .row class property.

Comment: Okay, yes, makes more sense to pad the .row, I guess. Thanks.